# Show page in designer

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have added new form Xamarin XAML page to my project. If I do View Designer my Visual Studio 2019 shows xaml file code, but not designed form. How to see page in design mode?

Content of Page1.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="App.Page1">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!"
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Content of Page1.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace App
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class Page1 : ContentPage
    {
        public Page1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: there is not a design surface for Xamarin XAML

Comment: Instead, use [Hot Reload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/hot-reload).

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin is dead, long live Maui! Seriously, there's no reason to start using Xamarin in 2023, Maui is designed to replace it and is actively maintained.

That said, there is no designer for either of them (or WinUI3, which Maui uses in Windows as a backend). You just learn to read and write XAML.

The good news is that you can edit the page code at run-time and see your changes in real-time, which is even better than a designer, because all bindings get re-bound as you type them so you can just use the UI with your changes and have it be fully functional.

Comment: *"see your changes in real-time"*: That is, question-asker should read about "Hot Reload".

Comment: There is nothing to read about, it's on by default and there is no configuration to it (besides disabling it). It will either just work, or just not.

Comment: Yes and no. Its useful to know the name of a concept. google `site:stackoverflow.com xamarin hot reload`. Without the name, its impossible to search for help if have a problem. And its useful to know its limitations. Consider [XAML Errors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/hot-reload#xaml-errors): *"If there are any such errors on the page, Hot Reload won't apply changes, even if made on other parts of the page. Fix all the errors for Hot Reload to start working again for the page."*

Answer (score 0):

Just as ToolmakerSteve said, you can use [XAML Hot Reload for Xamarin.Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/hot-reload).

With Hot Reload, when you save your XAML file the changes are reflected live in your running app. XAML Hot Reload plugs into your existing workflow to increase your productivity and save you time. Without XAML Hot Reload, you have to build and deploy your app every time you want to see a XAML change.

If you are starting from a template, XAML Hot Reload is on by default and the project is configured to work with no additional setup. Debug your Android, iOS, or UWP app on an emulator or physical device and change your XAML to trigger a XAML Hot Reload.

If you're working from an existing Xamarin.Forms solution, no additional installation is required to use XAML Hot Reload, but you might have to double check your configuration to ensure the best experience. First, enable it in your IDE settings:

- On Windows, check the `Enable XAML Hot Reload` checkbox (and the
  required platforms) at `Tools` > `Options` > `Debugging` > `Hot Reload`. In
  earlier versions of Visual Studio 2019, the checkbox is at `Tools` >
  `Options` > `Xamarin` > `Hot Reload`.
- On Mac, check the `Enable Xamarin Hot Reload` checkbox at Visual Studio

  > `Preferences` > `Tools for Xamarin` > `XAML Hot Reload`. In earlier versions of Visual Studio for Mac, the checkbox is at Visual Studio >
  > `Preferences` > `Projects` > `Xamarin Hot Reload`.

For more information,please check document: [XAML Hot Reload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/hot-reload).